# AssertJ testing on a collection: what is better: 'extracting' or Java8 forEach

Tags: java, junit, assertj

I'm new to AssertJ and using it to unit-test my written code and was thinking how to assert a list.

Lets assume we have a list of Consumers Entities. each Entity has it own Phone, own ServiceProvider which has it own Name and EntityName.

Now we want to assert that each Entity from a repository gets the right data, so we want to test that each item on list has equal Phone.

```
ConsumerEntity savedConsumer1 = Consumer(phone, name, serviceProvider)
List<ConsumerEntity> consumerListFromRepository = repository.findAllByPhone(phone)
```

Now I want to test that the data given from Repository is correct,

I can use this:

```
   assertThat(consumerListFromRepository)
            .extracting(ConsumerEntity::getPhone())
            .containsOnly(savedConsumer1.getPhone());
```

Or I can do this with forEach (java 8):

```
   consumerListFromRepository.forEach(consumerEntity ->
   assertThat(consumerEntity.getPhone()).isEqualTo(savedConsumer1.getPhone()));
```

**1.** Which one is faster/simple-r/readable? I will go for the forEach for less lines of code but less read-ability as well.

**2.** Is there any other way to do it 1liner like the foreach but with asserThat? so it will be readable and simple - and without the need to use EqualTo each

time? something like:

```
   asserThat(list).forEach........
```

**3.** Which one is faster? Extracting or forEach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that "faster" is a primary concern here. It's likely that any performance difference is immaterial; either the underlying implementations are ~equivalent in terms of non-functionals or - since the context here is a unit test - the `consumerListFromRepository` is trivially small thereby limiting the scope for any material performance differences.

I think your main concerns here should be

- Making it as easy as possible for other developers to:

  - Understand/reason about your test case
  - Edit/refactor your test case
- Ensuring that your approach to asserting is consistent with other test cases in your code base

Judging which of your two approaches best ticks this box is somewhat subjective but I think the following considerations are relevant:

- The Java 8 `forEach` construct is well understood and the `isEqualTo` matcher is explicit and easily understood
- The AssertJ `extracting` helper paired with the `containsOnly` is less common that Java8's `forEach` construct but this pairing reads logically and is easily understood

So, IMHO both approaches are valid. If your code base consistently uses AssertJ then I'd suggest using the `extracting` helper paired with the `containsOnly` matcher for consistency. Otherwise, use whichever of them reads best to you :)

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! you are right - speed is useless here as it is a test.

Comment: I agree with @glytching, I just want to add that the foreach option does not produce the same error message as using extracting + containsOnly which would show the entire collection of extracted values.
you can also give a try to [allSatisfy](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#allSatisfy-java.util.function.Consumer-).

Comment: @JoelCostigliola good call ... the readability consideration also encompasses the output from a failed assertion.

Comment: Thanks joel. will check that